# How can I set the color value channel delimiter in visual studio 2017

Tags: c#

I turned on my PC today and for some reason, the visual studio had an error so I had to reinstall it.

Anyways, today I was working on a project and when I tried to put a color by using RGB (into the properties tab) I had to use `;` instead of `,`

Is there a way to configure this?

**EDIT:** It doesn't happen only with the color, it does too with the size, location property, etc.

Comment: Did you change your system culture recently?

Comment: @HosseinEbrahimi What is it? I don't thing I changed anything since I reinstalled vs2019, also, it happens with vs2017 too.

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but I once saw on a machine that system culture or formatting settings, etc. was not en-us I had to use '/' instead of '.' for floating point numbers in different apps' settings(as it is used in persian language). try to set your culture setting to en-us. That may solve it.